# jQuery `.click` handler not working after return to page with browser back button

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

> I was able to find the answer before posting. Thought I would share the post anyway for future ref.

The issue was the turbolinks gem preventing the JS to be loaded without refreshing the page.

To fix, Remove:

`gem 'turbolinks'` from Gemfile  &

`//= require turbolinks` from application.js

> start of initial question (skip, unless interested in what didn't work)

Rails app using CoffeeScript

I have a page that displays the `.project-container` div along side of a `.profile-click`. When `.profile-click` is clicked the `.project-container` slides out of the way to show the '.profile-container' div.

This all works perfectly on the initial load or refresh of this page. The `.click` handlers do not function when the page is 'revisited' after a click of the browser's back button. (the divs targeted by `.click` are not on the page from which the browser back button is clicked)

Also, this is only an issue if I visit another page within the same app (ie main.com/sub -> browser back clicked -> main.com). Not a problem if the page is 'revisited' after going to another domain.

Hoping to gain some insight in to why this is happening.

```js
$(document).ready ->
  $('.project-overlay').click ->
    $('.project-container').animate 'right': '8.5vw'
    $('.project-overlay').animate 'right': '8.5vw'
    $('.project-overlay').css 'z-index': '0'
    $('.profile-container').fadeOut()
    $('.profile-click').fadeIn()
    return
    
  $('.profile-click').click ->
    $('.project-container').animate 'right': '65vw'
    $('.project-overlay').animate 'right': '65vw'
    $('.project-overlay').css 'z-index': '1'
    $('.profile-container').fadeIn()
    $('.profile-click').fadeOut()
    return
  return
```

I understand that `$(document).ready` isn't being fired on the reload (browser caching). This was confirmed by calling `alert('ready'`) which only popped up on the initial load.

> what didn't work

I tried to call `.ready` on a different div container that only exists on the initial page but it gave the same results.

`.onpageshow` is not working either

Tried to prevent caching in `application_controller` with no luck.

```js
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery
  before_filter :prevent_caching

  protected

  def prevent_caching
    response.headers["Cache-Control"] = "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
    response.headers["Pragma"] = "no-cache"
    response.headers["Expires"] = "0"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue was the turbolinks gem preventing the JS to be loaded without refreshing the page.

To fix, Remove:

`gem 'turbolinks'` from Gemfile &

`//= require turbolinks` from application.js